# MySQL - How to set a label for a column

Tags: php, mysql, label

Consider this table

```
CREATE TABLE `tblstaff` (
`id` INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`firstname` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
`lastname` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
`theme` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
`navbar` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
`role` ENUM('admin','staff','super') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`status` ENUM('Active','Suspended') NOT NULL,
`hash` TEXT NULL,
INDEX `PRIMARY_KEY` (`id`)
)COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci' ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;
```

I need to set a label for each columns in the database so that the PHP script can read it using the command

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM tbl_name
```

This is exactly as the "comment" column where the user can put anything, but I do not wish to use the comment column.

For example,

```
firstname => 'First Name'
lastname => 'Last Name'
role => 'User Role'
```

Any idea how to accomplish this? Is there any built in option for this ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the comment data?

Comment: Because it is already been used for the commenting purpose. This is more like a Label for the column

Comment: Name your columns as you want them to appear using backticks so that you can have multiple words. but you'll have to use `AS` on the PHP side when selecting.

Comment: create new table named f.g "labels" and put it there

Comment: Jay Blanchard: I would consider using "AS" option on the backend if the project is new and I am just starting it., but my case is different, I am nearly finished the work and there are about 20 tables and about 100 php files. Its is not worth to modify each php files.

Comment: @PawełMalisak  Good suggestion, I am thinking about this at present.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view with the desired aliases for columns.

Comment: How? can you explain or provide a sample?

Comment: The original table is left as it is, then the view is like a wrapper:

    
CREATE VIEW tblstaffs_labeled_view AS 
SELECT 
`id`,
`firstname` as 'First Name',
`lastname` as 'Last Name',
`email`,
`password`,
`theme`,
`navbar`,
`role`,
`status`,
`hash`
 FROM tblstaffs;